# typescript - can't access added returned variable

Tags: typescript

The SQL query -

```
  const currency = req.query.currency; - the query options: "BTCUSD" | "ETHUSD" | "LTCUSD"

    const allPrices = await Crypto.findAll({ attributes: [currency, 'createdAt'], order: [['createdAt', 'ASC']], raw: true });
```

The `Crypto` -

```
class Crypto extends Sequelize.Model<IDBCryptoAttributes> implements IDBCryptoAttributes {
  public id!: number;
  public BTCUSD!: number;
  public ETHUSD!: number;
  public LTCUSD!: number;
  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
}
```

`allPrices` objects for example -

```
  {
    BTCUSD: '4526.341078145248',
    createdAt: 2021-10-22T20:51:23.000Z,
  },
  {
    BTCUSD: '4600.428393851253',
    createdAt: 2021-10-22T20:52:24.000Z,
  },
```

Adding the first variable value from `allPrices` to the array before sending it to client -

```
const toClient = allPrices.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        return item;
      }

      return {
        ...item,
        price: +item[currency] + +allPrices[0][currency],
      }
    });
```

`toClient` objects for example -

```
{
    BTCUSD: '4526.341078145248',
    createdAt: 2021-10-22T20:51:23.000Z,
    price: 69989.82615963052
  },
  {
    BTCUSD: '4600.428393851253',
    createdAt: 2021-10-22T20:52:24.000Z,
    price: 70063.91347533654
  },
```

So I want to send it like this to the client -

```
res.status(200).send({
      success: true,
      message: "Successfully retrieved Historic prices",
      data: toClient.map((price) => ({
        price: price.price,
        createdAt: price.createdAt,
      })),
    });
```

The problem is -

```
Property 'price' does not exist on type 'Crypto | { price: number; id: number; BTCUSD: number; ETHUSD: number; LTCUSD: number; createdAt: Date; _attributes: IDBCryptoAttributes; _creationAttributes: IDBCryptoAttributes; isNewRecord: boolean; sequelize: Sequelize; _model: Model<...>; }'.
  Property 'price' does not exist on type 'Crypto'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: The objects in the `allPrices` array don't have a `price` property. But `toClient` contains the first object of that array without any modifications, thus the first object of `toClient` does not have a `price` property either (your example is wrong) and that's what the error is telling you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, the type `Crypto` doesn't contain the property price, so a type `Crypto | AnyOtherType` doesn't contain this property all the time.

In other words, in order to reference a property from a union type, it needs to be common between all the components of this type.

Specifically, the issue is in the following snippet, where you apply the change to all elements except the first, which results in a union type. Maybe you can explain why the special treatment to the first element.

```js
   const toClient = allPrices.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        return item;
      }

      return {
        ...item,
        price: +item[currency] + +allPrices[0][currency],
      }
    });
```

However, if you'll accept `undefined` or `null` instead of the price for the first element, then you can do the following, to check whether the object contains the `price` property.

```js
const data = toClient.map((price) => ({
    price: "price" in price ? price.price : undefined,
    createdAt: price.createdAt,
}))
```

Comment: What if I can't accept undefined or null instead of the price for the first element?
I have to get all of the data.

And the special treatment -
the first value is the full currency usd value, every other value from the first is the difference.
did that for storage reasons

Comment: price: 'price' in price ? price.price : +price[currency],

did that.

Comment: I don't think your approach is very robust, as you are relying on order by a date to retrieve an essential value. I think you should rethink your domain representation, maybe consider this value as an extra column or a relation. But I guess this is outside the scope of the question.
If this helped solve your issue, you can accept it!